# How to use a constant from a trait when defining a struct?

Tags: rust, traits

The following code:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait MyTrait {
    const FOO: usize;
}

struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait> {
    v: [u32; <T as MyTrait>::FOO],
    p: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

gives me the following compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: MyTrait` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:8:14
  |
4 |     const FOO: usize;
  |     ----------------- required by `MyTrait::FOO`
...
7 | struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait> {
  |                 -- help: consider further restricting this bound: `T: MyTrait +`
8 |     v: [u32; <T as MyTrait>::FOO],
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `MyTrait` is not implemented for `T`
```

([Link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b401c6286ad7eb8cc55a34eea15106f7))

How can I successfully use `FOO` when defining my vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, [you can't](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43408).

Array lengths cannot use generic parameters. This is an issue that results from the way constants and generics are implemented and interact with each other in the compiler and has been worked on for a few years with slow improvements.